# Use the heat kernel “magic rule” to solve the initial value problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Use the heat kernel to solve the initial value problem:
$$u_t(x, t) − ku_{xx}(x, t) = 0$$ $$∀x ∈ \mathbb{R}, t > 0$$

subject to-

$u(x, 0) = x^2 − 3x − 1$ $∀x ∈ \mathbb{R}.$

Ive started by using the "magic rule" for the heat kernel which gives me:

$$u(x,t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^\frac{-(x-y)^2}{4kt}(y^2-3y-1)dy$$

and then I made $σ=y-x$ therefore I get

$$u(x,t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^\frac{-σ^2}{4kt}((σ+x)^2-3(σ+x)-1)dσ$$

that simplifies to:

$$u(x,t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^\frac{-σ^2}{4kt}(σ^2+2σx+x^2-3σ-3x-1)dσ$$

I don't really know where to go from here so if anyone could help me that would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess you do not know about the [gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral). Some parts in your integral are odd. For the $\sigma^2$ you might integrate by parts.